# Trouble mapping ng-selected object to string model

Tags: angularjs

I have the following types:

```
$scope.types = [{
  name: 'First',
  desc: 'first desc'
},{
  name: 'Second',
  desc: 'second desc'
}]
```

I create a select:

```
  <div>
    <select ng-model="object.type" ng-selected="type.name" ng-options="type.name for type in types"></select>
  </div>
```

And my model looks like this:

```
$scope.object = {type: 'First'};
```

When I set that model the select box is not selected to the correct element.  Pretty sure I know exactly why this is happening.  My type list is a list of objects and my model.type is just a string not an object.  I really do want my types to have the extra 'desc' information and cannot change the model.  Is there a way to set-up my select such that it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the comprehension expression to

```
ng-options="type.name as type.name for type in types"
```

Answer (score 0):

Or....

Just assign it in the scope like this:

```
$scope.object = {type: $scope.types[0]}
```

Comment: The object only ever has one type. The select box is a list of available types. Again you can only choose one.

Comment: I've edited my answer.  Basically I'm just trying to show you that you can (and typically do) use the entire "type" object as the model for the select.  It gives you a lot more flexibility.  In this case the "object" object now has both .type.name and .type.desc properties.